# How to create pagination that shows previous and next 3 pages

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to show a pagination which only shows the recent and next 3 pages, but I can't get it working.

Here's my current code:

```
$stmt = MySQL::connection3()->prepare("SELECT COUNT(ID) AS TOTAL FROM products");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$total_pages = ceil(intval($row["TOTAL"]) / $results_per_page);

foreach (range(1, $total_pages) as $i) {
     if ($i == $page) {
          ?>
          <li class="page-item active">
               <a href="?page=<?php echo $i; ?>" class="page-link"><?php echo $i ?></a>
          </li>
          <?php
     } else {
          ?>
          <li class="page-item">
               <a href="?page=<?php echo $i; ?>" class="page-link"><?php echo $i ?></a>
          </li>
          <?php
     }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to give us a proper problem description first of all - “can't get it working” is not one.

Comment: There's no '3' in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create this example you can run and adapt with your code:

```
<style>.active{color:green!important}</style>
<?php
echo get_pagination_links('10','100');




function get_pagination_links($current_page, $total_pages)
{
    $links = "";
    if ($total_pages >= 1 && $current_page <= $total_pages) {
         $i = max(2, $current_page - 3);
                 
        for (; $i < min($current_page + 4, $total_pages); $i++) {
            if($i==$current_page){
            $links .= "<li class='page-item active'><a href='?page=$i;' class='page-link'>$i</a></li>";   
            }else{
            $links .= "<li class='page-item'><a href='?page=$i;' class='page-link'>$i</a></li>";
            }
        }
        
    return $links;
}
}


  ?>
```

Output:
7-8-9-**10**-11-12-13

obviously I didn't connect a database and therefore I used a static result

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, this works fine, except the first 3 pages don't show anything.

Comment: I tried the code and the first 3 have the right url. can you write with which result you tested?

Comment: I tested it with $current_page as 1 and $total_pages as 2.

Comment: I got it working, by changing the $current_page <= $total_pages - 3 to $current_page <= $total_pages and by setting $i = max(1, $current_page - 3);

Comment: perfect  :) nice job